# Не могу установить pandas

Tags: python, pandas, macos

Выдает вот такую ошибку. Вообще не понимаю, в чем дело и как решить эту проблему. (Не в в виртуальном окружении не работает, ни напрямую)

[image: вот]

Comment: Какие у вас версии Python, OS, включая архитектуру (битность)?